# Blazor WASM OIDC authentication issues with Google Identity Provider

Tags: authentication, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I am trying to set up SSO login/logout for a Blazor WebAssembly app (.NET 7).

For the Google Identity Provider (IP):

I have set up a new app in Google Cloud APIs, and I'm using the MS example from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

I have not altered anything from the defaults, other than assigning my proper Client ID.
Immediately I run into 3 issues:

1. After the login, `Context.User.Identity.Name` is empty, so the greeting message in `<LoginDisplay/>` does not display the user's name.
2. When I log out and back in, the account selection screen is skipped. So if I want to log on as a different user, I am SOL.
3. When I log out, in, and out again, the javascript gets confused and thinks I'm still logged in (see pic below)

[image: Issues 1 and 3]

For issue #2 I discovered I can add

```
options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters.Add("prompt", "select_account");
```

to the `AddOidcAuthentication` callback in Program.cs, which should fix the issue, right? Well, partially. It does show the account selection scren now, but at the cost of extra 10 seconds of waiting during a) logout, b) "checking login state" phase, c) the initial "Authorizing" phase during startup. Digging deeper, it seems like the requests sent during these phases have the same problem:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=<the client id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7241%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&state=<state id>&nonce=<some value>&prompt=none&prompt=select_account`

=> `prompt` gets 2 values, which causes the response to be a 302 redirect to:
`https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/error?authError=<some value>&client_id=<my client id>` and a 403 error.

(Also as a bonus, issue #3 seems to be fixed in this case.)

I hope I've given enough info for a repro, it really is a bog standard template setup.

My hunch is that there are bugs in the Javascript file (`_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js`) that handles authentication.

Has anyone been able to make the above work normally? I was planning to use Blazor for a frontend in a software project we are tasked with implementing, but from the above issues I get the feeling that it's not mature enough yet. I'll raise a bug with Blazor if indeed it is one, but I just wanted to cross-check with the community first -- I don't think it's a misconfiguration from my side.

As a footnote, I also tried with a Microsoft IP. I'll detail my woes in another post!